# Validate ajax html elements int existing form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a form (validated using jQuery Validate) with a select box that, when changed, inserts new elements into form:

```
  ctype.on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails")', type: 'POST', data: { id: $(this).val(), cntr: $('#ID').val() } })
        .then(function (result) {

            $('#fields').html(result).show('clip', {}, 500);
        },
```

The problem is that I am not able to add validation rules because element.Form property Is null for these new elements (and it's quite right).
Is there any workaround or special procedure to inform that these new elements belogs to that form? (Anyway, the post request is done correctly and I can see all the data on server side)

Comment: try `$.live('change', function() {...});`. Not quite sure what you mean if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: No, it is not. The problem is that element.forms of new added element using ajax is null, and validation attribute cannot be parsed.